# perl json map create issue

Tags: json, perl

i'm new in perl (i don't know almost nothing :-)) 
I had a script which worked on my local computer but not in server :-(

It looks like:

```
my $json = JSON->new;
my $json_map = [];


for (my $i = 0; $i <= $#commitlist; $i++) {
    my %co = %{$commitlist[$i]};
...

    push $json_map, {esc_html($co{'id'})=> {author=>esc_html($co{'author'}),pubDate=>$cd{'rfc2822'},link=>$co_url, title=>esc_html($co{'title'})}};


}

my $output = $json->encode($json_map);
print $output . "\n";
```

It worked and result was like this:

```
[{"id":{"author":"johny","title":"some title","link":"http://127.0.0.1","pubDate":"Fri, 14 Mar 2014 12:31:17 +0000"}}]
```

But now I have on server following problem (there is perl 5.8.8 version, but i would like to fix it in the script):

Type of arg 1 to push must be array (not private variable) at XX line XX, near "};"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do a push you need to de-reference the first argument (i.e. the array you're pushing things into). Like this:

```
push @$json_map, ...
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Newer versions of Perl (since 5.13 or so) accept an array reference to `push`, which is probably why it worked on the questioner's local machine.